# Broken Pipe com sockets em python

Tags: python

Estou tendo o seguinte erro sempre que tento enviar uma mensagem do servidor para o cliente usando sockets no Python:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
server:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = 5008
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = s.accept()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    msg = input("mensagem:")
    s.send(bytes(msg.encode()))
```

cliente:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'localhost'
port = 5008
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    msg = input("mensagem:")
    s.send(msg.encode())
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
```

Comment: Poste o código diretamente aqui, editando a pergunta.

Comment: Como pedido fiz o edit no post incluindo o código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mais grave é esta linha do lado servidor: `s.send(bytes(msg.encode()))` deve ser: `conn.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))`, e está a fazer de maneira errada o encode/decode (parto do príncipio que está com python3.x), neste caso até pode específicar o *char encoding* que quer, neste caso UTF-8, faça o seguinte:

**SERVIDOR:**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9000))
    sock.listen(5)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    conn.send('WELCOME\n(isto veio do servidor)\n'.encode())
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        conn.send('(isto veio do servidor)... A sua menssagem foi: {}\n'.format(data).encode('utf-8'))
```

**CLIENTE:**

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9000))
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        msg = input('messagem\n')
        sock.send(msg.encode())
```

NOTA: isto é um servidor pronto para um só cliente (conecção, socket), caso queira mais conecções ao seu servidor terá de adiocinar paralelismo (threading por ex) no lado do servidor, para que haja um processo para cada cliente

Comment: obrigado amigo o erro mesmo estava no s.send() e não no .encode() mesmo assim sua ajuda para apontar o erro foi fundamental