# Fazer servidor socket no tkinter permitir a entrada de clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, servidor, socket, tkinter

O programa funciona corretamente, ele cria um servidor para seu usuário, o servidor abre sem problemas. Mas quando utilizo um client para poder acessá-lo, aparece a seguinte mensagem no client do servidor:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\JF Andrade\Desktop\ScriptsPython\Programa011(Cliente_Servidor).py", line 10, in 
>       sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
>   ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente.

Algúem poderia explicar o porque deste erro? Desde já obrigado.**

Lado Servidor

```
from tkinter import *
from socket import *
import time




 class AdminTools(object):
      def __init__(self, main):


            self.font = ("Verdana", "8", "bold")

            self.Frame1 = Frame(main)
            self.Frame1["bg"] = "LightBlue"

            self.LabDiv2 = Label(main,text = "-----------------------------------------------------------")
            self.LabDiv2["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.LabDiv2.pack()


            self.Lab1 = Label(main,text = "Bem-vindo ao Server Manager", fg = "Red", font = self.font)
            self.Lab1["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.Lab1.pack()

            self.LabDiv1 = Label(main,text = "-----------------------------------------------------------")
            self.LabDiv1["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.LabDiv1.pack()

            self.Lab2 = Label(main, text = "CRIAR NOVO SERVIDOR ", fg = "Green")
            self.Lab2["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.Lab2.pack()

            self.Lab3 = Label(main, text = "HOST:", fg = "Black")
            self.Lab3["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.Lab3.pack()

            self.Txt1 = Entry(main, bg = "LightGrey", fg = "Red")
            self.Txt1.pack()

            self.Del1 = Button(main, bg = "Red", text = "Del", command = self.ExcluirTexto, width = 6)
            self.Del1.pack()


            self.Lab4 = Label(main, text = "PORTA:", fg = "Black")
            self.Lab4["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.Lab4.pack()


            self.Txt2 = Entry(main, fg = "Red", bg = "LightGrey")
            self.Txt2.pack()


            self.LabSpc1 = Label(main,text = "")
            self.LabSpc1["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.LabSpc1.pack()


            self.Bt1 = Button(self.Frame1, text = "CRIAR SERVER", fg = "Black", bg = "Green", command = self.CriarServer, width = 12)
            self.Bt1.pack()
            self.Frame1.pack()

            self.LabSpc1 = Label(self.Frame1, text = "", pady = 0)
            self.LabSpc1["bg"] = "LightBlue"
            self.LabSpc1.pack()

            self.Bt2 = Button(self.Frame1, text = "FECHAR SERVER", bg = "RED", width = 12, command = self.FecharServer)
            self.Bt2.pack()

    def ExcluirTexto(self):
                    self.Txt1.delete(0, END)



    def CriarServer(self):
                    Host = str(self.Txt1.get())
                    Port = int(self.Txt2.get())
                    sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
                    sockobj.bind((Host, Port))
                    sockobj.listen(5)
                    print("Servidor iniciado")
                    self.Lab3["text"] = "SERVIDOR INICIADO COM SUCESSO!"
                    self.Lab3["fg"] = "Blue"                                                               




  AdminTools(main)

  main.title("Server Manager v1.0")

  main["bg"] = "LightBlue"

  main = Tk()

  main.geometry ("300x300")

  main.mainloop()
```

## Lado Cliente

```
  from socket import *

   serverHost = 'localhost'
   serverPort = 45




   sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
   sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))
   print("Conexão estabelecida")
```

Comment: Vou colocar no post.

Comment: Olha mas mesmo assim o servidor não parece estar muito bem, dá uma olhadela aqui... https://github.com/Miguel-Frazao/simple-chat , não tem tkinter mas é um servidor multi-threading (multiplos clientes) de chat... Podes pôr servidor a correr extended que tem mais prints para veres o que está a acontecer

Comment: Eu ja estou trabalhando em um servidor multi-thread, este é um de testes. Mas tem como explicar o que houve no servidor de testes?

Comment: O código que puseste do servidor dá-me que main não está definido. E não devias fazer um ciclo infinito para que o servidor fique a correr?

Comment: Quando coloquei o loop para mantê-lo online e clico em criar server ele resolve crashar.

Comment: Dá uma olhadela aqui, na resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166545/broken-pipe-com-sockets-em-python

Answer (score 1):

O problema desse código é que embora a função que crie um socket para o servidor seja chamada, ela não faz nada além disso: cria um novo servidor, o conecta a porta, diz que vai ouvir até 5 conexões e em seguida "acaba" - ao acabar, todos os objetos criados dentro dela, que estão referenciados fora do escopo da função são destruídos pelo Python (e se por acaso o Python não fizesse isso, você teria um socket no sistema, ocupando a porta, mas sem ter como acessa-lo a partir do código em Python).

Na prática os seus sockets são destruídos frações de segundo depois de serem criados - é necessária uma chamada ao  método `accept` que vai parar a execução do seu programa (e congelar a interface do tkinter), enquanto aguarda por uma nova conexão.

Então para fazer isso funcionar de fora que faça algo, não é só colocar uma chamada a a `socketobj.accept` no final do método  `CriarServer` - idealmente vocÊdve estabelecer um timeout para o socket, chamar o accept - e, caso haja uma conexão de chegada, gerenciar isso em uma série de funções que funcionem como eventos to tkinter - e não fazer nenhuma chamada bloqueante aos sockets (seja `accept`, seja `recv`)  se um timeout. Você pode ar listas e dicionários do Python para gerenciar várias conexões ao servidor na thread principal - ou usar uma thread por conexão - mas aí vai ter que pensar numa forma dessas threads funcionarem bem em conjunto com o tkinter.

Pode funcionar por aí se for um programa de baixa demanda de recursos: um chat pessoal, ou um teste para uso em intranet. Se for um servidor para um serviço que pode precisar escalar para centenas (ou mesmo vária dezenas) de clientes, o melhor é não tentar usar o mesmo em conjunto com o tkinter - escreva o servidor usando asyncio,  e crie um programa em tkinter (ou mesmo uma página Web, por que não?) para ser a interface que também se conecta como cliente, mas com capacidades especiais. Dessa forma não precisa se preocupar em dividir os recursos do processo que é seu servidor com toda a parte gráfica que o tkinter tem que gerenciar.

Answer (score -1):

Isso Parece um pouco estranho:

```
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

Ao invés de:

```
sockobj = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: drk3, seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. No caso da sua resposta o ideal é que seja explicativa informando geralmente o que a pessoa errou e porque. quando é uma resposta curta, o melhor seria adicionar um comentário à pergunta. Seguem algumas dicas sobre como fazer uma boa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: No código, é feito `from socket import *` em vez de `import socket` - o que joga todos os nomes definidos em  `socket.*` no namespace atual. Ou seja: isso não é o problema, definitivamente.