# Como receber vários pedidos socket em um só servidor?

Tags: python-3.x, socket

Olá! Estou a fazer um programa esquema servidor / cliente em Python no qual queria ter apenas um servidor e vários clientes.

Imaginemos ter 3 clientes cada um a fazer um pedido ao servidor por ligação socket, como é que:

- 1: O servidor conseguiria aceitar mais do que uma ligação socket ao mesmo tempo?
- 2: O servidor realizaria as tarefas (tinha pensado numa base de dados para armazenar os pedidos e servir de cache)

Obrigado!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é ler o [Guia de Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: Quando você dá um Listen em um IP/Porta, cada nova conexão cria um socket novo. Basta ir armazenando estes sockets em uma lista sempre que tiver uma conexão nova (sem bloquear) e em seguida fazer um loop percorendo a lista e coletando os dados de cada uma. Ao fim, é bom liberar a CPU antes de fechar o loop principal. Fazendo não-bloqueante, você estará gerenciando várias conexões ao mesmo tempo. O segredo é só tomar uma ação quando em alguma das capturas de dado contiver um comando completo a ser respondido. Para uma resposta mais objetiva, é melhor dividir a duvida em perguntas separadas.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pela explicação, existe algum site onde eu poderia ver um exemplo de código para perceber melhor?

Comment: Não sei se isso ajuda: https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html (só dei uma olhada por cima, é algo um pouco mais simples do que eu falei, mas talvez sirva como base). Normalmente não uso Python no dia a dia (mas socket é parecido na maioria das linguagens).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta para o teu primeiro ponto é "sim", o servidor consegue aceitar e processar mais do que uma conecção temos é de o preparar para isso.

[Neste exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166545/broken-pipe-com-sockets-em-python) o servidor consegue lidar com uma só conecção, mas agarrando nisso conseguimos implementar o suporte para várias conecções, vamos ter de implementar *threads*, em que cada conecção no servidor é uma `thread`/`processo` "independente".

Em baixo está um exemplo simples de um servidor de chat, comentado onde acho que deva ser explicado:

Server:

```
import socket, threading

def run(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024) # receber informacao
        if not data: # se o cliente tiver desligado
            conns.remove(conn)
            break
        for c in conns: # enviar mensagem para todos os outros clientes
            if c is not conn: # excepto para o que a enviou 
                c.send('{}: {}'.format(conn.getpeername(), data.decode()).encode('utf-8'))

conns = set() # armazenar conxoes aqui
host, port = ('', 9999)
with socket.socket() as sock: # ligacao TCP
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # reutilizar endereco logo a seguir a fechar o servidor
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(5) # servidor ativo
    print('Server started at {}:{}\n'.format(host, port))
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept() # esperar que alguem se conect
        conn.send('WELCOME {}'.format(addr).encode())
        conns.add(conn) # adicionar conexao ao nosso set de coneccoes
        threading.Thread(target=run, args=(conn,)).start() # esta coneccao vai ser independente das outra a partir de agora, vamos correr a thread na funcao run
```

Cliente:

```
import socket, threading, sys, select

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('', 9999))
    while True:
        io_list = [sys.stdin, s]
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(io_list , [], [])
        for io in ready_to_read:
            if io is s: # se tivermos recebido mensagem
                resp = s.recv(1024)
                if not resp:
                    print('server shutdown')
                    sys.exit()
                print('{}'.format(resp.decode()))
            else:
                msg = sys.stdin.readline() # vamos enviar mensagem
                s.send(msg.encode())
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

Quanto ao teu ponto 2 também dá, apesar de não perceber bem o que queres guardar na base de dados.

Caso queiras guardar as conecções podes por exemplo (neste exemplo vou guardar num ficheiro), acrescentar isto por baixo da ultima linha (`threading.Thread(...`) do exemplo de servidor que coloquei em cima:

```
...
with open('conns.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('{}\n'.format(':'.join(addr)))
```

Comment: Ajudou muito! Obrigado pela explicação e pelos exemplos de código fornecidos!

Comment: De @HiperBolt, ainda bem

Comment: Só uma pergunta adicional, a função sock.accept() retorna dois argumentos, neste caso conn e addr. conn corresponde a quê exatamente? (estou só a verificar que estou a perceber tudo)

Comment: Não retorna dois, retorna um tuple, ex: (conecção, ('213.32.12.2', 4324)), nós é que fazemos o unpacking, em que conecção é a própria conecção, é com ela que o teu servidor vai trabalhar, para mandar mensagens, fechar etc... por exemplo em vez de `conn, addr = sock.accept()` , podias só `dados_conn = sock.accept()` em que `dados_conn[0]` seria a tua conecção e `dados_conn[1]` é o endereço da mesma

Comment: Percebi, mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: Dispõe @HiperBolt